# PHP select statement with bind

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a sign-up form through PHP, with prepared statements and bind parameters, like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$selectStatement = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? ";
$stmts = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $selectStatement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmts,'s', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmts);
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmts);

if (!$stmts){
    die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
}
while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmts)){
    if($row != null){   
        echo('User already registered!');
    }
    }else{  
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
        $stmtI = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insertQuery); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtI, "ss", $email, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtI);
        echo('Registration completed!');
}
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmts);  
mysqli_stmt_close($stmtI);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

But when no user is found in the database, it's supposed to go on the else branch, yet, apparently it's not getting there, not even in the while loop. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you do not have any results, the `while` will not even start, so there is no way of going to the else, it does not even get to the if!  And that makes your `if` superfluous as well, if you get in the `while`, there is a `$row` that is != null.

Comment: Please don't store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While loop is only execute when records found from database (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmts))**

You have to change your code like this

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; $selectStatement = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? "; 
$stmts = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $selectStatement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmts,'s', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmts);
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmts);
if (!$stmts){ die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
}
    if($count){
            echo('User already registered!');
    }else{
            $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
            $stmtI = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insertQuery); 
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtI, "ss", $email, $password);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtI);
            echo('Registration completed!');
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: I tried with the count method before also, but for some reason it always returns 0, even if the user is in the database.

Comment: Add this code after mysqli_stmt_execute

/* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

Comment: Yes,  the store_result function was all that was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is Wrong ... at

```
}
}else{
```

only write

```
}else{
```

try this

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$selectStatement = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? ";
$stmts = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $selectStatement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmts,'s', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmts);
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmts);

if (!$stmts){
    die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
 }
while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmts)){
if($count == 1){
    echo('User already registered!');
}else{
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
    $stmtI = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insertQuery);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtI, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtI);
    echo('Registration completed!');
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmts);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmtI);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Good catch for the `}`, I hadn't notice!

Comment: use IDE like NetBeans that will help you to not get syntax error.

Comment: Note i replaced    if($row != null){   to  if($count == 1){

Comment: That takes for granted that users do not share an email address.  In most systems that should not occur anyway, but I have seen exceptions.

Comment: Oh yes that { too, but that wasn't the problem, and i also tried with the count before but it always return 0 for some reason, even if the user is in the database.

Comment: Oops ... Why you use while loop !? that wasn't the problem ... but you don't need to use while loop here ...